# How I use node modules in laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, node-modules

In my resource/assets/js I have tests.js ,I use gulp to build all files from js including this one ,in this file I have

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd');

cmd.get(
    'echo 3',
    function(data){
        console.log('You are returning: ',data)
    }
);`
```

I want to use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) but not in root directory in public directory or in other directory than root,is any possibility to use require funcion for example from public folder using gulp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Elixir to mix your JavaScript files in your `assets` folder into (1 `app.js` file in) your public folder.

Take a look at [the documentation on Elixir and JavaScript](https://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir)

**Note however**, that both NodeJS and php are server side technologies and you should really know what you're doing to make them work together. Pushing NodeJS libraries in your public folder to use client side is ***NOT*** what NodeJS is made for and you should probably not use it that way.

Comment: Just to mention, that node.js is a serverside javascript environment....

Comment: You can use Elixir to move/mix your assets anywhere in your project. Besides OP specifically asked to move the JS files to his public directory.

Comment: I copy the js file but that file is maked to work with an other require 'var exec = require('child_process').exec;'(this one).
I am new with this and I don't know how to use require in other forder beside root one can you help me to understand how can I make to work ?

Comment: So copy that one as well, I guess?

Comment: Its from node itself.I searched for that one and 0 succes.

Comment: May I ask why you are both using php and JavaScript btw? Both are serverside technologies, as @pbwned already mentioned and I can imagine Node throwing all kinds of errors and exceptions when you use them in conjunction and especially when you put Node libraries in your public folder to use client side.

Comment: I make a SPA with angular but I wanted to make a test of that node module from public directory and i get 'require is not defined' after start the page.

Comment: That's probably because the pacakage should run serverside and thus does nothing clientside.

Comment: And how I make to run an serverside with angular?

Comment: I will put an other question for this problem ,thanks for everything.

Comment: No problem, I'd suggest using a MEAN stack altogether ;)

Comment: This has bad practice written all over it, but is appearantly the only solution, other than concatenating all your dependencies into a single file with gulp.